# Coloring a multirow

Tags: tables, color, multirow

i have currently this code in LaTeX

```
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}[c]{ll}
\caption[API da listagem de um docente]{API da listagem de um docente.}  \label{relStruct}\\
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textcolor{WhiteC}{\textbf{URL}} \cellcolor{GreenC}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{http://di76.di.fct.unl.pt:3007/people} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textcolor{WhiteC}{\textbf{Method}} \cellcolor{GreenC}} &  
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{GET} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}*{\textcolor{WhiteC}{\textbf{QueryString}} \cellcolor{GreenC}} & 
start= & The number of the first person to return \\  &  end= & The number of the last person to return \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{WhiteC}{\textbf{Returns}} \cellcolor{GreenC}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{200 OK \& XML (people/people+xml)} \\ &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{404 Not Found} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{center}
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{footnotesize}
```

And the output of this code its a table where the 2 multirow parts are not painted fully, only the top of the row its painted. Anyone can tell me how to fix these problem in order to paint completely?

Answer (score 10):

The best solution is to use `\colorcolumn`, for the first column, in the table format. Notice also that I changed `\mulrirow{2}{*}{...}` to `\mulrirow{-2}{*}{...}` to avoid problems with the text being overwritten by the color.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable,multirow,array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate some text

\colorlet{WhiteC}{white}% to make the example compilable
\colorlet{GreenC}{blue!60}% to make the example compilable

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}[c]{|>{\columncolor{GreenC}}l|l|l|}
  \caption[API da listagem de um docente]{API da listagem de um docente.}  \label{relStruct}\\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{GreenC}\textcolor{WhiteC}{\textbf{URL}}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{http://di76.di.fct.unl.pt:3007/people} \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{GreenC}\textcolor{WhiteC}{\textbf{Method}}} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{GET} \\ \hline
  & start= & The number of the first person to return \\ 
  \multirow{-2}{*}{\textcolor{WhiteC}{\textbf{QueryString}}} & end= 
    & The number of the last person to return \\ \hline
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{200 OK \& XML (people/people+xml)} \\ 
  \multirow{-2}{*}{\textcolor{WhiteC}{\textbf{Returns}}} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{404 Not Found} \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

There's no `footnotesize` environment; `\footnotesize` is a switch. I don't understand why you are using a `tabular` environment inside a `longtable`; use `longtable` if your table will admit page breaks and `tabular` otherwise. I redefined the colors `GreenC` and `WhiteC` to make my code compilable for everyone.

Comment: In the first column of the first two rows, you only need to enter `\textcolor{WhiteC}{\textbf{URL}}` and `\textcolor{WhiteC}{\textbf{Method}}`, respectively, as you've already used the `\columncolor` command. I.e., no need for the `\cellcolor` instructions, right?

Answer (score 7):

With **multirow** there are known problems when it's required to color a cell. I would define, in the preamble,

```
\newcommand{\mycell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\greencell}[1]{\textcolor{WhiteC}{\bfseries #1}\cellcolor{GreenC}}
```

and write the table as

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption[API da listagem de um docente]{API da listagem de um docente.}  \label{relStruct}
\medskip
\footnotesize

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\greencell{URL} & http://di76.di.fct.unl.pt:3007/people \\
\hline
\greencell{Method}&  GET \\
\hline
\greencell{QueryString} &
\mycell[l|l]{%
  start= & The number of the first person to return \\
  end= & The number of the last person to return} \\
\hline
\greencell{Returns} &
\mycell{200 OK \& XML (people/people+xml) \\
  404 Not Found} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The double row cells are input as argument to `\mycell`, which can receive an optional argument to express the kind of "subtabular" you need.

Whether you prefer this method or the `\multirow` method as in Gonzalo's solution is a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answers. It worked for both of the answers you gave me. :)

Really appreciate the fast answer. Cheers!

Comment: @Peddro: It would be fair to mark your preferred solution as the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\multirow{-n}{*}{...}` on the nth row and `\rowcolor{color}` on each i'th row (i=1..n). This solves the problem of `\rowcolor` not coloring the following rows when using `\multirow`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you provide a working example of you answer? Longer answers are more appreciated `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and `\multirow{-n}{*}{...}` was not working for me.  The `-n` was the primary part.  However I used a similar format to the answer:

```
\begin{tabular}{  m{9cm} m{9cm} >{\columncolor{mygreen}}m{7.3cm}  }
```

Then for the multirow I put it in the final row and was able to successfully shift the text up using the option below.  `3` represents how many rows. `2.8` in the width of the internal text and `35em` is how much you want to shift it up.  You probably won't need a number as high as `35`.

```
\multirow{3}{2.8in}[35em]{lots of text...}
```