# Color and rules in tables with multirow

Tags: tables, color, multirow

I have a problem with colors and lines in tables.
I have this code:

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
        \begin{tabular}{ll|c|c|c|c|c|c|}  \cline{3-8} \cline{3-8}
         & & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{gray!25} Cramér von Mises} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{gray!25} Anderson-Darling} \\  \cline{3-8} \cline{3-8}
         & & \cellcolor{gray!25}$\alpha=$0.1 & \cellcolor{gray!25}$\alpha=$0.05  & \cellcolor{gray!25}$\alpha=$0.01 & \cellcolor{gray!25}$\alpha=$0.1 & \cellcolor{gray!25}$\alpha=$0.05 & \cellcolor{gray!25}$\alpha=$0.01 \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \cellcolor{gray!25}n=25 & 0.106 & 0.063 & 0.015 & 0.107 & 0.052 & 0.012 \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \cellcolor{gray!25}n=50 & 0.107 & 0.043 & 0.010 & 0.103 & 0.054 & 0.010 \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{3}{0.3cm}[7mm]{\begin{sideways}$\qquad$ $Exp(1)$ \end{sideways}}}&\cellcolor{gray!25} n=100 & 0.104 & 0.065 & 0.017 & 0.110 & 0.055 & 0.015 \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \cellcolor{gray!25}n=25 & 0.113 & 0.055 & 0.014 & 0.097 & 0.058 & 0.016 \\ 
         \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \cellcolor{gray!25}n=50 & 0.109 & 0.058 & 0.014 & 0.098 & 0.056 & 0.018 \\ 
         \multicolumn{1}{|c}{ \multirow{3}{0.3cm}[7mm]{\begin{sideways}$\qquad$ $Exp(2)$ \end{sideways}}} & \cellcolor{gray!25}n=100 & 0.110 & 0.048 & 0.011 & 0.108 & 0.044 & 0.009  \\ \hline
          \end{tabular}
```

I need to color the multirow cell and the only thing I could arise was to color the lower part of it.

My other problem is when I coloured the cells, I cant see properly the rules of the table.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21155/coloring-a-multirow

Comment: This code does not even compile.

Answer (score 5):

Always supply a complete, but minimal document. Yours is missing `\documentclass` as well as `\begin` and `\end` document. It is also missing the loading of `xcolor` (for the color names like `gray!25`) and `rotating` (for the `sideways` environment). To color the whole multirow you need to color all three cells of it. Also, your use of `\multirow` is incorrect. If you want to put the text into the cells above it, the number should be negative. If you do that, you don't need the optional adjustments of `[7mm]` nor the `\qquad`s. I've done a few other things I think make the result better: Taking `Exp` out of math mode, putting the numbers after `\alpha=` into math mode, removing some errant spaces, and removing most of the vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,xcolor,colortbl,rotating}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{ll|cccccc|}  \cline{3-8} \cline{3-8}
   &&\multicolumn{3}{c} {\cellcolor{gray!25} Cram\'er von Mises}&
     \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{gray!25} Anderson-Darling}\\
  \cline{3-8} \cline{3-8}
   &&\cellcolor{gray!25}$\alpha=0.1 $ &\cellcolor{gray!25}$\alpha=0.05$&
     \cellcolor{gray!25}$\alpha=0.01$ &\cellcolor{gray!25}$\alpha=0.1 $&
     \cellcolor{gray!25}$\alpha=0.05$ &\cellcolor{gray!25}$\alpha=0.01$\\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{gray!25}} & \cellcolor{gray!25}n=25 & 0.106 & 
    0.063 & 0.015 & 0.107 & 0.052 & 0.012 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{gray!25}} & \cellcolor{gray!25}n=50 & 0.107 & 
    0.043 & 0.010 & 0.103 & 0.054 & 0.010 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{gray!25}%
    \multirow{-3}{*}{\begin{sideways}Exp$(1)$\end{sideways}}}&
    \cellcolor{gray!25}n=100 & 0.104 & 0.065 & 0.017 & 0.110 & 0.055 & 0.015 \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{gray!25}} & \cellcolor{gray!25}n=25 & 0.113 &
    0.055 & 0.014 & 0.097 & 0.058 & 0.016 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{gray!25}} & \cellcolor{gray!25}n=50 & 0.109 & 
    0.058 & 0.014 & 0.098 & 0.056 & 0.018 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{gray!25}%
    \multirow{-3}{*}{\begin{sideways}Exp$(2)$\end{sideways}}}&
    \cellcolor{gray!25}n=100 & 0.110 & 0.048 & 0.011 & 0.108 & 0.044 & 0.009  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

(I've also broken the lines so people reading this don't have to scroll three screens over to see the whole code.)

Answer (score 4):

I think that the ConTeXt interface for handling multiple rows and columns is much nicer as it provides a clean separation of content and presentation. For example, without any styling, the above table can be typeset as (I simply copy pasted the data in the Exp(2) part).

```
\starttext

\bTABLE
  \bTR
    \bTD[nc=2] \eTD
    \bTD[nc=3] Cramér von Mises \eTD
    \bTD[nc=3] Anderson-Darling \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD[nc=2] \eTD
    \bTD $α = 0.1$  \eTD
    \bTD $α = 0.05$ \eTD
    \bTD $α = 0.01$ \eTD
    \bTD $α = 0.1$  \eTD
    \bTD $α = 0.05$ \eTD
    \bTD $α = 0.01$ \eTD
  \eTD
  \bTR
    \bTD[nr=3] \rotate{Exp(1)} \eTD
    \bTD $n = 25$ \eTD
    \bTD 0.106 \eTD
    \bTD 0.063 \eTD
    \bTD 0.015 \eTD
    \bTD 0.107 \eTD
    \bTD 0.052 \eTD
    \bTD 0.012 \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD $n = 50$ \eTD
    \bTD 0.107 \eTD
    \bTD 0.043 \eTD
    \bTD 0.010 \eTD
    \bTD 0.103 \eTD
    \bTD 0.054 \eTD
    \bTD 0.010 \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD $n = 100$ \eTD
    \bTD 0.10R \eTD
    \bTD 0.065 \eTD
    \bTD 0.017 \eTD
    \bTD 0.110 \eTD
    \bTD 0.055 \eTD
    \bTD 0.015 \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD[nr=3] \rotate{Exp(2)} \eTD
    \bTD $n = 25$ \eTD
    \bTD 0.106 \eTD
    \bTD 0.063 \eTD
    \bTD 0.015 \eTD
    \bTD 0.107 \eTD
    \bTD 0.052 \eTD
    \bTD 0.012 \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD $n = 50$ \eTD
    \bTD 0.107 \eTD
    \bTD 0.043 \eTD
    \bTD 0.010 \eTD
    \bTD 0.103 \eTD
    \bTD 0.054 \eTD
    \bTD 0.010 \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD $n = 100$ \eTD
    \bTD 0.10R \eTD
    \bTD 0.065 \eTD
    \bTD 0.017 \eTD
    \bTD 0.110 \eTD
    \bTD 0.055 \eTD
    \bTD 0.015 \eTD
  \eTR

\eTABLE


\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Now, lets add styling one by one. First, create a setup to add the frames:

```
\startsetups table:frame
  \setupTABLE[frame=off]

  \setupTABLE[row][1,3,6][topframe=on]
  \setupTABLE[row][last][bottomframe=on]

  \setupTABLE[column][1,3][leftframe=on]
  \setupTABLE[column][last][rightframe=on]

  % Correct for spanning cells.
  \setupTABLE[6][2][rightframe=on]
  \setupTABLE[1][6][bottomframe=on]

  % Correct for missing top left cell
  \setupTABLE[1][1,2][topframe=off, leftframe=off]

\stopsetups
```

and use is using

```
\bTABLE[setups={table:frame}
```

which gives:

[image]

Next add the background to the top row and left column by creating another setup

```
\startsetups table:background
  \setupTABLE[background=color]
  \setupTABLE[row][1,2][backgroundcolor=gray]
  \setupTABLE[column][1,2][backgroundcolor=gray]

  % Correct for missing top left cell
  \setupTABLE[1,2][1,2][background=]
\stopsetups
```

and use it using:

```
\bTABLE[setups={table:frame, table:background}]
```

which gives:

[image]

Finally, correct the alignment and spacing by creating a new setups:

```
\startsetups table:style
  % Middle align all data columns
  \setupTABLE[align={middle,lohi}]

  % ... except the 2nd column
  \setupTABLE[column][5][align=flushleft]

  % Add spacing
  \setupTABLE[loffset=0.25em, roffset=0.25em]

\stopsetups
```

and using it using:

```
\bTABLE[setups={table:frame, table:background, table:style}]
```

which gives:

[image]

Note that the code is much more readable than in LaTeX, and it is relatively easy to change the style in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I'm new using this thing and that ugly code was the best I could haver done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (as provided by `array`) but adds new functionalities.

In particular, when the key `corners` is used, the empty corners are automatically computed by `nicematrix`. Then the commands which draw rules (eg `\Hline` provided by `nicematrix` and similar to `\hline`) and color cells take into account that corners.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|ll|cccccc|}[corners]  
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!25}{1,2}
  \columncolor{gray!25}{1,2}
\Body
\Hline
   && \Block{1-3}{Cramér von Mises}&&& \Block{1-3}{Anderson-Darling} \\
   &&$\alpha=0.1 $ &$\alpha=0.05$& $\alpha=0.01$ &$\alpha=0.1 $& $\alpha=0.05$ &$\alpha=0.01$ \\
\Hline
  \Block{3-1}{\rotate Exp$(1)$} 
   & n=25 & 0.106 & 0.063 & 0.015 & 0.107 & 0.052 & 0.012 \\
   & n=50 & 0.107 & 0.043 & 0.010 & 0.103 & 0.054 & 0.010 \\
   & n=100 & 0.104 & 0.065 & 0.017 & 0.110 & 0.055 & 0.015 \\
\Hline
  \Block{3-1}{\rotate Exp$(2)$} 
   & n=25 & 0.113 & 0.055 & 0.014 & 0.097 & 0.058 & 0.016 \\
   & n=50 & 0.109 & 0.058 & 0.014 & 0.098 & 0.056 & 0.018 \\
   & n=100 & 0.110 & 0.048 & 0.011 & 0.108 & 0.044 & 0.009  \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

The rules won't seem to disappear under the colored panels, whatever PDF viewer you use.