# multirow, colortbl and booktabs: Problem including \cmidrule and \cline (white line) when using cellcolor

Tags: tables, multirow, colortbl

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    margin = 5mm,
    landscape,
    %showframe,
    ]
    {geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\renewcommand{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\belowrulesep}{0pt}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}    % loads also colortbl
\definecolor{myTableColor}{gray}{0.80}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lc|l|X|X|X|X}
\toprule
\rowcolor{myTableColor}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Text}} & Text & Text & Text & Text & Text\\
\midrule
Text & \cellcolor{myTableColor} & & & & & \\
%\cmidrule{3-7}
\cline{3-7}
Text & \cellcolor{myTableColor}\multirow{-2}{*}{A} & & & & & \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{Text} & & & & & \\
\midrule
Text & \cellcolor{myTableColor} & & & & & \\
\cmidrule{3-7}
%\cline{3-7}
Text & \cellcolor{myTableColor}\multirow{-2}{*}{A} & & & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

% \multirow{-2}{*}{A} is taken from user Gonzalo Medina
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21155

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

- I have `multirow` and `cellcolor`.
- I want to use `\cmidrule`from `booktabs`.
- I get a weird while line.
- `\cline` works fine.
- I also tried `\cmidrule[0pt]`.
- Also, the line width of `\cmidrule` and `\midrule` seems to be different.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you do not want to use `\cline`?

Comment: @Bernard I wanted to use the `booktabs` rules (mid/top/bottom). The `cline` has a different width. But maybe I just should `google` how to change the line width :).

Comment: The `makecell` package defines the `\xhline` and `\xcline` commands, and `boldline`, from the `shipunov` bundle have such commands, `\hlineB` and `\clineB`, with a slightly different syntax.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. I don't have much experience with tables and I will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does more or less what you want with `makecell` and a `\Xcline{3-7}{0.05em}`: the value of `0.05em` is the default thickness of `\midrule` (`\lightrulewidth`). As to `\cmidrule`, the default is `0.03em`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    margin = 5mm,
    landscape,
    %showframe,
    ]
    {geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\renewcommand{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\belowrulesep}{0pt}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % loads also colortbl
\definecolor{myTableColor}{gray}{0.80}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lc|l|X|X|X|X}
\toprule
\rowcolor{myTableColor}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Text}} & Text & Text & Text & Text & Text\\
\midrule
Text & \cellcolor{myTableColor} & & & & & \\
\Xcline{3-7}{0.05em}
Text & \cellcolor{myTableColor}\multirow{-2}{*}{A} & & & & & \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{Text} & & & & & \\
\midrule
Text & \cellcolor{myTableColor} & & & & & \\
\Xcline{3-7}{0.05em}
Text & \cellcolor{myTableColor}\multirow{-2}{*}{A} & & & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

% \multirow{-2}{*}{A} is taken from user Gonzalo Medina
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21155

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Never used `makecell` before -- thanks!

Comment: What's funny is these thick rule commands are only a by-product of `makecell`: it mainly aims at allowing line breaks and a common formatting of cells like column heads.

Comment: I read (roughly) the docu yesterday in bed -- seems pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can use directly `\midrule` and `\cmidrule` of `booktabs` with the expected output.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[a4paper,margin = 5mm,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\belowrulesep}{0pt}

\usepackage{nicematrix}


\definecolor{myTableColor}{gray}{0.80}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{lc|l|X|X|X|X}
\toprule
\RowStyle[rowcolor=myTableColor]{}
\Block[l]{1-2}{\textbf{Text}} & Text & Text & Text & Text & Text \\
\midrule
Text & \Block[fill=myTableColor]{2-1}{A} & & & & & \\
\cmidrule{3-7}
Text \\
\midrule
Text \\
\midrule
Text & \Block[fill=myTableColor]{2-1}{A} & & & & & \\
\cmidrule{3-7}
Text \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabularX}
    
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code looks very elegant.